# Material-UI: You are using the typography variant

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I develop a web app using react and Material-UI and react. when I use pagination I got below error.

```
index.js:1452 Warning: Material-UI: You are using the typography variant caption which will be restyled in the next major release. 
Please read the migration guide under https://material-ui.com/style/typography#migration-to-typography-v2
```

I use below way in pagination in my code

```
import TablePagination from '@material-ui/core/TablePagination';

<TablePagination
    component="div"
    count={this.handleChangeFilter(searchedVal).length}
    rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
    page={page}
    backIconButtonProps={{
        'aria-label': 'Previous Page',
    }}
    nextIconButtonProps={{
        'aria-label': 'Next Page',
    }}
    onChangePage={this.handleChangePage}
    onChangeRowsPerPage={this.handleChangeRowsPerPage}
/>
```

please tell me how slove it error image in below

[image]

Comment: Please share snippets of your use of the `Pagination` component, and the version of Material-UI you are working with.

Comment: yes, I used in the new version.

Comment: I will added code to pagination.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This error means the typography will change in the next version ,so you should migrate to the next version.The https://v3.mui.com/style/typography/#migration-to-typography-v2 give you a guide on how to migrate to the next version by adding this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    useNextVariants: true,
  },
});
```

Comment: Actually this is a problem about the version about @material-ui/core/.I run an example in https://codesandbox.io/s/x38315w52p,first with the version 3.2.0,and I face this problem, then I change the version to 3.1.2,and the warning gone.In my opinion, it's just a warning, you can ignore it.However,if you want to make this gone, you can change the version of @material/core or you can read the this issue in github in https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/releases/tag/v3.2.0.

Comment: @ThilinaSampath if you found the solution, post it

Comment: I added typography to my createMuiTheme block and that did it for me

Answer (score 2):

If you are using createMuiTheme, you should provide this new theme in the following way:

```
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import TablePagination from '@material-ui/core/TablePagination';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    typography: {
        useNextVariants: true,
    },
});

export default class Sample extends PureComponent {
    render(){
        return(
            <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
                <Tablepagination/> //add your pagination setup
            </MuiThemeProvider>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem and I found this solution that really works!

Check out the link here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54668516/10120050