# Deprecated typography warning when using custom theme in Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In the following code code, I am using a custom theme in Material-UI:

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import { purple, green } from "@material-ui/core/colors";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: purple,
    secondary: green
  }
});

function App() {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Button color="primary">Button1</Button>
      <Button color="secondary">Button2</Button>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

I am getting the following warning:

`Warning: Material-UI: you are using the deprecated typography variants that will be removed in the next major release.`

I am not using any typography (let alone any deprecated typography variant)

Why am I getting this warning? Can someone please explain.
Full demo at codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/r5v9pjxnq4

Minimal repro code: https://codesandbox.io/s/p9628o7wlj
(Turns out just using `createMuiTheme` also gives the warning!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expanded error message links to https://material-ui.com/style/typography/#migration-to-typography-v2 which explains the message in more detail.

Above this you find the deprecated variants which include `button`. It's not actually deprecated but will be restyled which some consider a breaking change which is why we log this warning.

I agree that it's a bit overzealous to warn just by using createMuiTheme but I suspect that 95% of the use cases touch deprecated variants in some way.

Comment: Any chance to deactivate the warning for unit tests? I don’t want to have to inject a theme with the correct property set into any component I want to test…

Answer (score 6):

I just add in my `index.html`:

```
<script>window.__MUI_USE_NEXT_TYPOGRAPHY_VARIANTS__ = true</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone here this has been addressed in release v3.6.1